# I can not return an error message in CodeIgniter 3 callback

Tags: php, callback, codeigniter-3

I am new to CODEIGNITER, ... I can not send the message "E-mail already registered in the system", of the function "verifica_existe_email", by the callback.

```
public function users(){
    init_painel();
    $parametro = get_data_form('acao','get');
    switch ($parametro) {
        case 'cadastrar':
            set_tema('template','painel/usuarios/cadastrar');
            break;
        case 'insert';
            form_validation->set_rules('nome','nome','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|callback_verifica_existe_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('senha','senha','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('re-senha','repita a senha','required|matches[senha]');
            $sucesso = $this->form_validation->run();
            if($sucesso):
            else:
                set_tema('template','painel/usuarios/cadastrar');
            endif;
            break;
        default:
            set_tema('template', 'painel/usuarios/inicio_usuario');
            break;
    }
    load_template();

}

public function verifica_existe_email($email){

    $get_email = $this->usuarios_model->verifica_campo('email_usuario',$email);

    if($get_email):
         $this->form_validation->set_message('verifica_existe_email','Email já cadastrado no sistema');
        return 
    else:
        return FALSE;
    endif;

}
```

Comment: Please translate your title into English, or submit in Portuguese on [pt.so].

Comment: `case 'insert';` should be `case 'insert':`

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but unfortunately the error persists :'(

Answer (score 0):

As I am unsure, I changed the return

```
if ($ get_email):
                 $ This-> form_validation-> set_message ('verifica_existe_email', 'Email already registered in the system');
                  Return TRUE;
                  Else:
                      Return FALSE;
                  Endif;
 for

If ($ get_email)
                 $ This-> form_validation-> set_message ('verifica_existe_email', 'Email already registered in the system');
                  Return FALSE;
                  Else:
                      Return TRUE;
                  Endif;
```